# Pointer arithmetic in memcpy has weird result

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I am coming back to C programming after some years so I guess I am a bit rusty, but I am seeing some weird behavior in my code.

I have the following:

```
memcpy(dest + (start_position * sizeof(MyEnum)), source, source_size * sizeof(MyEnum));
```

Where:

- `dest` and `source` are arrays of `MyEnum` with different sizes,
- `dest` is 64 bytes long.
- `source` is 16 bytes long.
- `sizeof(MyEnum)` is `4` bytes
- `source_size` is `4`, as there are 4 enums inside the array.

I am looping this code 4 times, advancing `start_position` at each time, so at each of the 4 loop iterations I get `memcpy` being called with the following values (I already checked this with the debugger):

1. `memcpy(dest + (0), source, 16);`  (`start_position` = 0 * 4, since `source` size is 4)
2. `memcpy(dest + (16), source, 16);` (`start_position` = 1 * 4, since `source` size is 4)
3. `memcpy(dest + (32), source, 16);` (`start_position` = 2 * 4, since `source` size is 4)
4. `memcpy(dest + (48), source, 16);` (`start_position` = 3 * 4, since `source` size is 4)

`memcpy` works fine on the first loop, but on the second it copies data to another array instead, clearly going outside the memory region of `dest` array, violating another array's memory area.

So I checked the pointer arithmetic happening inside my function and this is what I got:

- `dest` address is `0xbeffffa74`
- `dest + (start_position * sizeof(MyEnum))` is `0xbefffab4` for `(start_position * sizeof(MyEnum)` = `16`
- The array being violated is at `0xbefffab4`.

Although this explains why the array's memory is being violated, I don't get how `0xbeffffa74 + 16` is going to be `0xbefffab4`, but I can confirm that's the address that `memcpy` is being called at.

I am running this on a Raspberry Pi, but AFAIK this shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pointer arithmetic works on the size of the pointed datatype. If you have a `char*` then ever time you increment the pointer it’ll move by one. If it’s an `int*` then every increment adds more than one, usually 4 to the pointer (due to int usually, but not always, being 32bit).

If you have a pointer to a struct then incrementing the pointer moves it by the size of the struct. Therefore the `sizeof` shouldn’t be there or you’ll move way too much.

```
memcpy(dest + (start_position * sizeof(MyEnum)), source, source_size * sizeof(MyEnum));
```

This moves the pointer 4*4 bytes every position since the `MyEnum` is four bytes.

```
memcpy(dest + start_position, source, source_size * sizeof(MyEnum));
```

This moves it only 4 bytes at a time.

This is logical because `pointer[2]` is the same as `*(pointer + 2)` so if pointer arithmetic didn’t implicitly take the pointed type size into account all indexing would also need the `sizeof` and you’d end up writing a lot of `pointer[2 * sizeof(*pointer)]`.

Comment: `a[b]` is the same as `*(a+b)`. That means `(a+b)` must be the same as `&a[b]`. Now, consider `int a[2];`. If you want the second element of `a`, you would use `a[1]` not `a[1* sizeof(int)]`. That means `*(a+1)`, not `*(a+1*sizeof(int))`. And thus, for the address of the second element `(a+1)`, not `(a+1*sizeof(int))`. So why are you multiplying by `sizeof(myEnum)` if you wouldn't multiply by `sizeof(int)`?

Comment: Yeah, looking by this perspective makes total sense, I just forgot about the classic `*(a+b)` and was just thinking about bytes. Too bad I was downvoted on this question as the answer here seems a lot better than those on the duplicates.